# convertion into integer linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am trying to model the Ising spin state problem into Integer linear program and find the optimal ground state using lp_solve. (This is just a miniature version of Ising state problem)

$$
maximise: \sum J_{ij}S_{i}S_{j}
$$
$$
-1\leq J_{ij} \leq 1
$$
$$
S_{i},S_{j} \epsilon (-1,1)
$$
Value of $J_{ij}$ is given.
The goal is to find optimal values of $S_{i}$ to maximise the value. 
For ex:
$J_{12}=1, J_{13}=-1, J_{23}=-1$. One of the solutions for maximum energy is 3 with $S_{1}=1, S_{2}=1, S_{3}=-1$.

I am finding it difficult to convert this into integer linear program.

This is my initial approach for the conversion.
I tried to take an aditional variable $X_{i}$ and convert this program as
$$
maximise: \sum X_{i}
$$
$ if((S_{i}=-1 or S_{j}=-1) and J_{ij}=-1) \implies X_{i}=1 $
$ if((S_{i}=-1 or S_{j}=-1) and J_{ij}=1) \implies X_{i}=-1 $
$ if((S_{i}=-1 and S_{j}=-1) and J_{ij}=-1) \implies X_{i}=-1 $
$ if((S_{i}=-1 and S_{j}=-1) and J_{ij}=1) \implies X_{i}=1 $

I dont know if this approach is correct or not. Even i dont know how to convert this to linear program.
Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is poor etiquette to cross-post: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30944/convertion-into-integer-linear-program-for-ising-spin-state-problem?noredirect=1#comment70351_30944
Truth be told, however, this is the better forum to ask your question. Perhaps you should delete it over there.

Comment: @michael grant I will take your suggestion. I didnot know which is the right forum to ask this question.

Comment: Well, you have good answers over there now. What is done is done.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other thread, it really would be best to solve this using a binary quadratic programming engine. Nevertheless, it can indeed be converted to a binary linear program.

Consider this equation:
$$\bar{S}_i + \bar{S}_j = 2 X_{ij} + Y_{ij}$$
where $X_{ij},Y_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ and 
$$\bar{S}_i = (1-S_i)/2 = \begin{cases} 1 & S_i = -1 \\ 0 & S_i = +1 \end{cases}  \qquad i=1,2,\dots, n.$$
Then $Y_{ij}=0$ if $S_i=S_j$ and $Y_{ij}=1$ if $S_i\neq S_j$, and
$$S_i S_j = (-1)^{\bar{S}_i+\bar{S}_j} = 1 - 2Y_{ij}.$$
Note that if $i=j$, $S_iS_j=1$, so the corresponding $J_iS_iS_j$ term is a constant that will not change the optimal result. So we need only consider the $i\neq j$ cases.
Therefore, we have this:
\begin{array}{lll}
\text{maximize}  &   \sum_{i,j:~i\neq j,~J_{ij}\neq 0} J_{ij}(1 - 2 Y_{ij}) \\
\text{subject to} & \bar{S}_i + \bar{S}_j = 2 X_{ij} + Y_{ij} & i,j:~i\neq j,~J_{ij}\neq 0\\
& \bar{S}_i\in\{0,1\} & i=1,2,\dots, n \\
& X_{ij},Y_{ij}\in\{0,1\} & i,j:~i\neq j,~J_{ij}\neq 0 \\
\end{array}
The problem here is that we have created $2n^2-2n$ new binary variables to accomplish this, or $n^2-n$ if $J_{ij}=J_{ji}$. This is likely to be more costly than just using a binary quadratic programming engine.